# What does "Therapist and client relationship" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning, vocabulary, synonyms, semantics

What does ***"therapist and client relationship"*** mean? And is there a short description for it or synonym?

> B:‘’My  mother  mentioned you, often.’’
>
> A: ‘’Strange,  she  never mentioned  you  to me.’’
>
> B: ‘’You asked no questions  of her?’’
>
> A: ‘’Not  really.  She  has  always  been  warm  and  inviting  with  me. Always  attentive  to  my  needs.  But,  she  always  held  herself rather… how  should  I  put  it?  Secretly…  yes,  I  always  felt  that  she  wanted  to keep  herself private.’’
>
> B: **"Sounds like a therapist and client relationship."**

Comment: I'm not sure this makes any sense. In a therapist/client relationship, the client tells the therapist everything.

Comment: A relationship between A and B. Where's the problem?

Comment: Yes that's right. Does it mean that because the therapist doesn't do the same as the client?

Comment: A is talking about B's mother.

Comment: @FeliniusRex: I think B is describing the relationship *as it relates to the therapist* (the *therapist* is supposed to avoid being too "open" herself, since anything she thinks or feels is just unwanted "noise" in the context of a therapy session).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Person B is referring to the concept of [client confidentiality](https://www.goodtherapy.org/blog/psychpedia/client-confidentiality).

> Confidential: marked by intimacy or willingness to confide

Because therapy involves discussing sensitive matters, therapists must be able to convince their clients to share information that the client may consider private.

This is made easier by the therapist's persona which is often warm, understanding, and non-judgmental. Additionally, the client knows that a therapist has a duty to not disclose information about their clients.

This exchange of information is one-sided, however. The therapist does not usually share their private thoughts with their client.

---

Like a therapist would be to their client, person B's mother was warm and inviting to person A and was always willing to discuss what was on person A's mind. She was attentive to person A's needs.

Also like a therapist, person B's mother did not share many details about herself with person A. There was an imbalance of information in the relationship that led to person A not knowing about person B despite person A being close to person B's mother.

Person B notes this dynamic and correctly compares it to the relationship between a therapist and their client.

---

Generally, you could say that person B's mother was a [confidant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confidant) for Person A. She was someone that person A trusted with private information, but Person A did not necessarily receive the same trust in return.

Comment: But in the context it doesn't make sense i think,  because A shares everything with the woman but on the other hand the woman is somehow private and closed and doesn't share to A.

Comment: You may need to add more context, then, because no part of what `Person A` says indicates that `Person A` is sharing with the woman. `Person A` may be lamenting a one-sided emotion in their relationship, but that is not clear from the dialog you have posted.

Comment: I added more context now

Comment: I modified my answer. The original interpretation is the same, but the roles of person A and the mother have been switched because of the additional context you added.